# Running jmeter through command line

Tags: command-line, jmeter

I'm new to jmeter. I have the .jmx file containg a http samplers and a view result `tree.CommandLine.jmx is the name of my testplan. I executed jmeter through command line using

```
jmeter -n -t CommandLine.jmx -l resultfile.jtl.
```

the resultfile.jlt is created but it doesn't contain anything.
So what is the problem with my resultfile?

Comment: Check log file. See if you are getting any error.

Comment: No Errors In log file

Comment: There is no error in syntax, Review your test plan once for configurations.

Comment: When i run it through GUI I can save the file using summary report save table data.I don't think there is problem with configuration

Comment: I tried executing the test plan in other computer and i got the resulting file. thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Better user aggregate report given by JMeter. Then you don't have to worry about storing result file manually.

Answer (score 0):

[image: jtl file Report]

It works fine with below script

```
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\Post_call_24_FirstStep_10.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\resultfile.jtl
```

need to provide the path for .jtl file and remove . at the end. Need some correction in below sript

```
jmeter -n -t CommandLine.jmx -l resultfile.jtl.
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below command. Please find JMeter complete [tutorial](https://www.testodev.com/2018/06/learn-jmeter-for-free-step-by-step.html)

jmeter -n –t Your-JMX-file.jmx -l test-results.jtl

Comment: Pointing user to a tutorial is not an answer, but here it is possibly a spam. [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)